# How to create report for Notes object content?

Tags: reporting, notes, for

I have a requirement in which client needs monthly data of all the notes  related to every lead . This result in  huge data which I am doing manuallly now. I query data from workbench and prepare excel . Any suggestion on automating this process?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into power query in excel ( assuming available from office 2013+) . Super awesome toolset that will let you query salesforce objects. I was able to extract all notes into excel and you can apply regular data filters as you do in excel.

[image]